# android-How to put scroll view under scroll view

Tags: android

My application need to 2 scroll views(sv1,sv2). sv1 is main scroll view and sv2 is sub scroll view of sv1. 
   is it possible? then how to do it.

Following one is my answer. it is working in simulator only but not working in device means device  support sv1 only sv2 is not working.

How to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView android:id=”@+id/parent_scroll”
        android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
        android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
        android:layout_weight=”1″
        android:background=”@drawable/dotted_bg”
        android:focusableInTouchMode=”false”>
                    <LinearLayout   />
                    <LinearLayout   />
                    <LinearLayout  >
                    <ScrollView android:id=”@+id/child_scroll”  
                    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
                    android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
                    android:background=”@drawable/text_box_bg”>
                <TextView android:id=”@+id/text_description”
                    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
                    android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
                    android:textColor=”@color/gray”
                    android:textSize=”12dip”
                    android:padding=”5dip”
                    android:scrollbars=”vertical”/>
                <!–ScrollView>
              </LinearLayout>
```

Step 1 : Provide unique id to both the scrollview.
Step 2 : get reference of that two scrollview in your activity.

```
 parentScroll=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.parent_scroll);
 childScroll=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.child_scroll);
```

Step 3: Now set touch listeners for both.

```
        parentScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.v(TAG,”PARENT TOUCH”);
                findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                return false;
            }
        });
        childScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                Log.v(TAG,”CHILD TOUCH”);
                                    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Done …